# I have a JSON problem with HTTPClient library's POST request

Tags: arduino, esp32

I can't use the `POST()` function properly or don't know how to

I get this error message

> no matching function for call to 'HTTPClient::POST(ArduinoJson::JsonObject&)

When I try to send a JSON object inside the `POST()` function, I get the following return message:

```
{
  "error": "ParseError",
  "description": "Errors found in incoming JSON buffer"
}
```

When I try to simply write JSON as string in POST() function and try to send it that way

```cpp
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h> //v5.13.5

const char* ssid = "**";
const char* password = "**";


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(4000);
  WiFi.begin(ssid,password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) { //Check for the connection
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi..");
  }

  Serial.println("Connection established!");
  Serial.print("IP address:\t");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println("Connected to the WiFi network");


}

void loop() {
  if(WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED){
    HTTPClient http;

    http.begin("http://172.20.10.13:1026/v2/entities"); //My docker
    http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    StaticJsonBuffer<200> jsonBuffer;
    JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.createObject();
    root["id"] = "urn:ngsi-ld:Sensor:001";
    root["type"] = "motion";
    root["value"] = "No";
    root.printTo(Serial);
    /*int httpResponseCode = http.POST("{\n\t\"id\":\"urn:ngsi-ld:Sensor:001\", \"type\":\"MotionSensor\",\n\t\"value\":\"NO\"\n}"); */
    int httpResponseCode = http.POST(root);
    if(httpResponseCode > 0){
      String response = http.getString();

      Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
      Serial.println(response);
    }
    else{
      Serial.print("Error on sending POST: ");
      Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
    }
    http.end();
  }
  else{
    Serial.println("Error in WiFi connection");
  }
  delay(300000);
}
```

Result should be a functioning POST request into docker and data stored, while i can read that data with GET command in terminal on my VM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument for [HTTPClient.POST](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266HTTPClient/src/ESP8266HTTPClient.h#L184) is Arduino String (or a C string) and you can't simply pass your JSON object. You need to use [prettyPrintTo](https://arduinojson.org/v5/api/jsonobject/prettyprintto/) to convert your json object to a standard JSON string and next pass it to the `POST` function.

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h> //v5.13.5

const char *ssid = "**";
const char *password = "**";

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    delay(4000);
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
    { //Check for the connection
        delay(1000);
        Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi..");
    }

    Serial.println("Connection established!");
    Serial.print("IP address:\t");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
    Serial.println("Connected to the WiFi network");
}

void loop()
{
    if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED)
    {
        HTTPClient http;

        http.begin("http://172.20.10.13:1026/v2/entities"); //My docker
        http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        StaticJsonBuffer<200> jsonBuffer;
        JsonObject &root = jsonBuffer.createObject();
        root["id"] = "urn:ngsi-ld:Sensor:001";
        root["type"] = "motion";
        root["value"] = "No";
        root.printTo(Serial);
        /*int httpResponseCode = http.POST("{\n\t\"id\":\"urn:ngsi-ld:Sensor:001\", \"type\":\"MotionSensor\",\n\t\"value\":\"NO\"\n}"); */
        char json_str[100];
        root.prettyPrintTo(json_str, sizeof(json_str));
        int httpResponseCode = http.POST(json_str);
        if (httpResponseCode > 0)
        {
            String response = http.getString();

            Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
            Serial.println(response);
        }
        else
        {
            Serial.print("Error on sending POST: ");
            Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
        }
        http.end();
    }
    else
    {
        Serial.println("Error in WiFi connection");
    }
    delay(300000);
}
```

Comment: I think that did the trick for me, thanks a lot for the help. I am sorry i couldn't try this earlier and respond to you i was busy.